# Android Studio - Purpose of Play Store column

Tags: android-emulator

What is the purpose of *Play Store* column in **Select a Device** while creating a Android Virtual Device?

Comment: @Zoe, thanks for editing tags, didnt know that emulator has a separate tag

Answer (score 1):

It mean you have installed the Google Play image on android emulator, instead of the stock emulator image. The stock image is a barebone android image with basic play services and basic android system apps.

*Here are the differences in the images.*

Without Google Play icon:

- Google play store is not available.
- Only way to install any app is via adb or downloading/pushing and apk and launching apk.
- adb has root privileges.
- Google account service is not available
- Cant use google apps like Gmail, Google Photos etc.

With Google Play icon

- Google play store is available.
- Apk can be installed through Google Play, adb and download/push.
- adb do NOT have root privileges.
- Google account service is available.
- Can install any Google app available on play store.

Comment: thanks a lot, this is a very important thing to remember